# Как добавить в консоль команду при помощи модуля на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу библиотеку на Python. Мне нужно, чтобы она запускалась командой через консоль/терминал после установки через `pip`.

Я знаю, как обрабатывать консольные аргументы, но мне не ясно, как сделать вместо

```
python libname.py --args
```

Что-то такого формата

```
libname --args
```

Как пример такого применения можно взять библиотеку `auto-py-to-exe`, которая работает по такому же принципу.

Как реализовать подобное в своём модуле?

Answer (score 0):

"Как реализовать подобное в своём модуле?"

Для этого надо:

1. В первой строке python скрипта написать #! /usr/bin/python
2. Поместить Ваш скрипт в любой каталог, входящий в значение $PATH
3. Присвоить ему атрибут исполняемости: chmod 0755 <Имя скрипта>

После этого Ваш скрипт будет запускаться по команде <Имя скрипта> --args из консоли.